# Windows Phone 8.1 app ProgressRing not showing

Tags: windows, xaml

I am trying to show a progressring while storing data but I can not get it to show. My Xaml looks as follows:

```
 <Page
    x:Class="MyApp.MyPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Model="using:MyApp.Model"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar Height="58">
            <AppBarButton Icon="Save" Label="" Click="AddAppBarButton_Click"/>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>


    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Title Panel -->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="19,0,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="Name" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" Margin="0,12,0,0"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="nameTextBox" Margin="0,10,21.833,0" />
            <TextBlock Text="Item" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" Margin="0,12,-4.167,0"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="itemTextBox" Margin="0,10,96.833,0" PlaceholderText="" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                <AppBarButton Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Icon="AddFriend" Label="" Margin="88.167,-2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="66" Click="ItemAppBarButton_Click"/>
            <Grid Margin="0,0,-0.167,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
            <ListView x:Name="ItemListView" Height="379" Margin="0,10,21.833,0" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ItemListView_ItemClick">
                <ListView.DataContext>
                    <Model:Person/>
                </ListView.DataContext>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
        <ProgressRing Name="BusyProgressRing" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="169,299,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

When I do:

```
BusyProgressRing.IsActive = true;
```

It does not show. Because at the end of my member function I do a BusyProgressRing.IsActive = false; and the rendering of the ring only occurs after my whole function is done.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because *ProgressRing* does not appears in **design time**. It appears just **in Runtime**. You will see it when you deploy the application.

Additionally, ProgressRing always appears in the center of the screen. You don't have to write code for this.

Comment: I found out that setting the IsActive = true will only render after my member function I use it in is done. No idea how to fix that though.

Answer (score 0):

Tested your code and the ProgressRing works. I did remove the margins and correct issue with row/column position of some UI element in your code and add

```
IsActive = "True"
```

to the ProgressRing. Your original code (with the margins) puts ProgressRing outside visible area when tested on my desktop.